# Scroll farther down in spyder?

Tags: spyder

Wondering if there's any way to scroll farther down on spyder after your code reaches the bottom of the screen, so that the bottom of your code is in the middle/top of the screen. On a vertical monitor it strains your neck to constantly be looking down.

Answer (score 2):

Preferences < Editor < Display < check Scroll past the end